# Include custom directives on DTColumnBuilder renderwidth

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-datatables

Is there a way for DTColumnBuilder.newColumn.renderWidth to include custom directives? Here is a draft code of what I want to achieve.

```
DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('reportStructureName').withTitle('Structure Name')
    .renderWith((data, type, full) => {
          return "<my-directive></my-directive>"; 
     }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `$compile` the cell content in the `createdCell` callback. Here is a very simple example, with a directive that does nothing but coloring the text red. Sorry for not using arrow functions :)

```
$scope.data = [
     { reportStructureName : "structurename1" },
     { reportStructureName : "structurename2" },
     { reportStructureName : "structurename3" },
     { reportStructureName : "structurename4" }
]

$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withOption('data', $scope.data)
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers');

$scope.dtColumns = [       
   DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('reportStructureName')
    .withTitle('Structure Name')
    .renderWith(function(data, type, full) {
       return "<my-directive>"+data+"</my-directive>"; 
    })      
    .withOption('createdCell', function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
       $compile( td )( $scope ); //<--- here
    })  
]
```

Directive :

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
       angular.element(element).css('color', 'red')
    }   
  }
})
```

demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/aok6SyWZlLaQv8UsEVIf?p=preview**

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll try this one out and will update you. :)