# Angular-Datatable: How to unsanitize data in table cell

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I am using Angular Datatables for displaying records. But it seems that this table plugin automatically sanitizes the values in a cell.

For example if my data is "Test Record &GT" it will display "Test Record >" but my requirements says to display "Test Record &GT". So far I have explored the "createdCell" function and have created filters and directives to fix this but to no avail.

Here is my code when I used "createdCell"

```
.withOption('createdCell', function (cell, cellData, rowData, row, col) { 
                    $(cell).html(cellData); 
                })
```

But still it returns the sanitized data. Please help. Thanks :)

Comment: can you try $(cell).text(cellData); instead?

Comment: I have fixed my bug yesterday. It turns out that the saving logic for the data uses $sanitize. So the data retrieved from the database had already been sanitized. This gave me a large headache since I thought that the angular-datatable is the one doing the automatic sanitation.

Anyhow, I will mark Tirthraj Barot as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sanitize works on HTML not on `.text()`

But if you do `$(cell).text(cellData)` instead of `$(cell).html(cellData)` it won't sanitize and thereby your code won't be rendered to html and would be rendered in form of text.

Here is a fiddle to represent the difference between `.html()` and `.text()`
http://jsfiddle.net/hossain/sUTVg/

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Tirthraj Barot's answer since it will prevent HTML encoding, but the whole setup does really not make so much sense: Then `createdCell()` is called `cellData` is already populated to the `<td>`. So basically you just insert `cellData` once again, just as text.

A better approach is to use the "*&amp; trick*" in `renderWidth()`. Simply replace any `&` with `&amp;` - by that no HTML entity will be encoded into their special character, since they are obfuscated :

```
.renderWith(function(data, type, full) {
  return data.replace('&', '&amp;') //use /g if you have multiple &'s
})
```

This also ensures you can work with directives, as in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43361762/1407478) :

```
.renderWith(function(data, type, full) {
  return "<my-directive>"+data.replace('&', '&amp;')+"</my-directive>";
})
```

If you are populating `cellData` again, you will need to `$compile` again or wrap `$compile` into a `$timeout`. By replacing `&`'s you do not need that.

see demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/gmVAm7qvG9lXVsOgWg8K?p=preview**