# AngularJS-DataTables, the options are not working

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I'm trying to implements an older version of angular datatable, i'm using version 0.5.7 since the newer version are not compatible with angular 1.6.0- The problem is , the options does not seams to be working, every plunker or jsFiddle i've seen seams to also have the same problem. Does anyone know if the options support was remove or if there is another way to acheive that ? 
Here is my code,
I'm trying to load simple options in my controller

```
$scope.DTOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
.newOptions()
.withDisplayLength(1)
.withBootstrap()
.withDOM("<'row'<'col-md-3'l><'col-md-6'<'daterangep'>><'col-md-3'f>><'row'tip>");
```

And i'm calling it in my HTML

```
<table class="table table-hover members-table table-striped" id="tablePunchList" datatable="" dt-options="DTOptions">
<!-- ... -->
</table>
```

Comment: This is because L-lin in my opinion have made an extremely poor job of versioning. He simply "forgot" to branch the projekt, so any projekt, jsfiddle, plnkr etc in the world stopped working from one sec to another, if they were referencing latest build, for example in bower with  `"angular-datatables": "*"` I have complained but he believes it is common sense to scrap a projekt entirely and introduce a new one under the same name, funny story.

Comment: But ts still works, just you are explicit with referencing the **Angular1** version, see the demo in this recent answer  -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43361762/include-custom-directives-on-dtcolumnbuilder-renderwidth

Comment: Thanks i found my problem, for some reason the options are not linked directly to the directive, you need to load them by adding `datatables.options` to your app.js.

Comment: Yes, just looked at the app.js I'am doing fixes on right now - have  `'datatables','datatables.buttons','datatables.bootstrap','datatables.select', 'datatables.options','datatables.fixedheader',` as dependencies. quite a lot :)